# Problem with Azure Bot with QnA Maker using Bot Framework SDK V4

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I tried to follow [this](https://manojmittalblogs.blogspot.com/2019/08/learn-qnamaker-azure-bot-with-bot.html?showComment=1649160341218#c9026700378201618207) and doing it the same, for me there are 2 problems Nr.1 I still got an Echo in the Bot Frame Emulator and Nr.2 I wont get a message from the Webchat in azure. This is my EchoBot.cs code

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.
//
// Generated with Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio EchoBot v4.15.2

using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;


namespace EchoBot1test.Bots

{

    public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
    {

        public QnAMaker EchoBotQnA { get; private set; }
        public EchoBot(QnAMakerEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            EchoBotQnA = new QnAMaker(endpoint);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var replyText = $"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
            await AccessQnAMaker(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(replyText, replyText), cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var welcomeText = "are you a member of ...?";
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                  
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(welcomeText, welcomeText), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task AccessQnAMaker(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var results = await EchoBotQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
            if (results.Any())
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(results.First().Answer), cancellationToken);  
            }
            else
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system."), cancellationToken);
            }
        }




    }

}
```

I think i tried everythink... i don't know what else i can try.

I would be very happy if someone has an idea and if the question is poorly formulated I can change it! It is really hard for me to explain this.

Comment: HI Nils, did you check the console in the app-service of your chatbot.

Comment: Hi Hessel, i check it but there is nothing, i don't get a fail message

Comment: **Question 1:** `Did you get the expected response on bot emulator?` **Question 2:**  `If you are expecting some response from QNA endpoint, in that case did you check the output on QNA portal?` **Question 3:**  `Did you tried to call QNA endpoint from POSTMAN?`

Comment: Please also check if the channel blade shows errors.

Comment: Troubleshooting steps should be, first check if you are getting expected result on `QNA portal`, then call the QNA endpoint from POSTMAN, finally if above two steps work fine then be sure problem on your configuration or bot code. So share above answer for quick troubleshooting.

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron Question 1: Kinda, i can't send a picure but i get it like this; first i type the question after that the correct answer will get send and then i receive an echo of my own question. Question 2: What do you mean? i put in the appsettings.json all the 3 thinks i need, do you mean that? Question 3: how do i do that?

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiro i get the expected result on qnamaker.ai but not in my webchat in azure. I don't think the QNA endpoint from POSTMAN is working

Comment: So  If I  don't  misunderstood, you are getting expected output from `QNA portal` and emulator, then how did you publish your bot on azure?

Comment: I am assuming,, bot wasn't published on azure portal accordingly, apparently, you are not getting expected response from QNA maker on chat conversation.

Comment: I am really confused my self. Is there any way that we can communicate? like talking? i feel like i can't really explain was exactly the problem is, Im sorry. If not i can try to explain again what the problem is.

Comment: There is a simple QnA bot [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker) which might be of help. Rather than building a new bot, you could try simply deploying this bot and seeing if it works. [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) is a tool for testing REST APIs. I've linked the getting started docs. Basically, you want to send a request to the [QnA Maker API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-qnamaker/)

Comment: I am, but it is not working and i don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: You are doing wrong on, connecting the `app service` with the `azure bot`, follow the steps I have given, then after publishing your code from visual studio to `app service` create a `new app registration` on `azure active directory` then copy the `appId` and `app secrect` from `azure active directory` then create your `azure bot` with that `appId` and `app Secret`, , currently your bot cannot communicate with your `app service` due to this problem, it doesn't know which app should it communicate with. Let me know if any questions you have. You just need to follow the steps accordingly.

Comment: Hey, after i try this i will come back to you! That could be the solution!

Comment: Update; I did everything you told me in the azure active directory and azure bot, but i don't get a response from azure bot not even "hello and welcome" any idea why?

Comment: @Nils, Did you follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Cnewgroup%2Ccsharp) to deploy the sample bot? What broke, specifically?

Comment: Did you configured the `Azure Web App Service URL`? It has to copy from `web app service` then need to paste on `azure bot configuration` as this format `https://YourAppService.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`

Comment: i did. i really don't know why it is not working, i really did every step you told me

Comment: Could you please update your question what steps you have done, so that it can be clear how did you tried. There might be an obvious omission.

Answer (score 0):

### QNA Maker Portal

Firstly, I have added a simple QNA pair and tested on QNA Portal as follows:

[image]

### Testing on Postman

You can skip this part if you think that you are getting expected response on QNA Portal:

[image]

### Testing on emulator

[image]

**Note:** Once you are done up to this point as expected you are ready to deploy your bot on Azure.

### Bot Web App Service on Azure

[image]

**Note:** Copy the `URL` which has been marked red. It should be like `https://YourBotServiceName.azurewebsites.net`

### Publish your bot from Visual Studio

[image]

**Note:** The app service you have created earlier you should get that service on "app service instance" menu item like below. Select your app service and click on Finish.

[image]

### Azure Active Directory App Registration

If you have existing application just copy the "Application (client)" from `overview` and  `app secrets` from Certificates & Secrets as given the picture below.

[image]

If you don't have existing app then create new app as like below screenshot.

[image]

### Azure Bot

Now you need to register your Azure bot under Azure bot registration panel. Like below:

[image]

**Steps: 1** Go To Azure Portal Create a resource Blade

[image]

**Steps: 2** Type Azure Bot. Click on Create then fill-up the form as below: And click on Review + Create then click on Create. Wait until the deployment finishes.

[image]

**Note:** this `appId` and `app secret` would came from Azure Active Directory App Registration, which has shown above

[image]

**Note:** You can get `appId` and `App Secret` by creating App Registration in Azure Active Directory as below:

[image]

**Steps: 3**  Once the deployment finished, click on "go to resource" it would lead you to below page.

[image]

**Note:** Point to remember, the document you were following it seems that you didn't follow this steps. Because recently Azure bot has a update which is "Azure Web App Bot is deprecated" but the document you were following is little older. So you probably missed this very important steps. [Update can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned#create-the-resource)

[image]

### Configure Azure Bot Service URL

This is the steps you missed on your bot which is very important to interact with your web app service and Azure Bot other than bot cannot recognize the interaction between web app service to Bot.

So now click on Configuration under Settings menu the URL you have copied earlier from your Bot web app service like below

[image]

Paste here it should be like this format: `https://YourAppService.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`. Should be like below:

[image]

### Final test on Azure Web Chat

[image]

**Note:** If you are still having issue then go to channels on your Bot and check if you are getting any error like this. In that case check your Azure Active Directory `app Id`, and `app secret` is correct.

[image]

[image]

In addition if you need official QNA sample you can [download from here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/README.md#qna-maker-samples).

Comment: i tried to follow your guid but i don't receive any response from the Azure Bot. i think it was my fault because i got really confused on the App ID and App secret think and also i needed a application insight API Key, the one in the bot was wrong apparently.

Comment: You don't need `application inside`, did you published the steps I have given you? It would work accurately, may be you are missing somewhere again.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started you might also try this approach:

1. Create a new QnAMaker Knowledge base with at least one question and answer pair.
2. Train the KB and Publish it.
3. After you published the KB, you will see a button labelled Create Bot
4. Click this button, it will create a web app bot. You will be able to select the language you prefer
5. Open the web app bot and use Test in Webchat to test it.

After these steps you will have a working chatbot running on Azure. After that you can download the sourcecode and add the stuff you need.

Remark: Web app bots are officially depreciated but this shortcut is still working. And existing web app bots will be supported.

Comment: I did this already, but i think i will try this again then! Thank you

Comment: Its the shortest road to a working QnaBot that I know. Let me know if you get stuck

Comment: is the secret ID the App secret that i need for Azure Bot?

Comment: You should not have to change anything wrt app-id and secret

Comment: i mean i need them for the Azure Bot don't i? I got the App-ID but i am not sure what the App-Secret is. is it the Value or Secret-ID?

Comment: @Nils you just need to give the web app bot a name, select the language you want to use and select create Web App Bot. Why do you worry about app secrets. Its all prefilled

Comment: I just checked the process. It is really straightforward. As soon as you have published the knowledgebase, press Create Bot. Create Web APp Bot opens in Azure. Just give the bot a name in App Name (leave application insights off for now) , leave Microsoft App ID and password on Auto Create. And press CREATE. That is.

Comment: So the Web bot app is perfectly fine. But i want do used it with the Echo Bot (Bot Framework v4 .NET Core 3.1) and when i try to used with that, i will get: The bot encountered an error or bug. To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code. Do you have any idee?

Comment: If you have the Web App Bot in working order (did you test it?), you should download the sourcecode and work from there. You will need to setup deployment ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: If you value a good understanding of what bot development is, you might also start with the docs. They are actually pretty good. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cvs

Comment: Yes! The Web App Bot is working fine (Thank you for that). But i see that i don't have a App Service to do the setup deployment.

Comment: The appservice has the same name as the web app bot

Comment: i got it! let me test that

Comment: i am connected but i don't have a Repository or Branch

Comment: Thats a topic for a new SO question

Comment: so you mean that i need a existing repository?

Comment: Yep, so you can work locally on your botcode and push your new stuff to the hosted botcode

Comment: Are  you still workin on this Nils?

Comment: Yes i am! i will try this then!

Answer (score 0):

I've read through most of what's been said in here, and I can see it's getting a little confusing, so let me propose an alternative path to getting a basic bot working.

1. Download the [sample QnA bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker)
2. In the sample's `appsettings.json`, fill in your QnA details (I am assuming you already have a basic QnA KB ready. If not, follow the [QnA quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/Quickstarts/create-publish-knowledge-base) to create one)
3. Test locally (run the bot, essentially), verify the bot works using the Bot Framework Emulator
4. Follow the most recent [Publish to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Cnewgroup%2Ccsharp) steps to create a new **Multi Tenant** bot (UAMI and Single Tenant are more complex, so leave them aside for now). I'd advise creating **all new** resources for testing just to make things simpler
5. Once you create a new app registration, add the App Password you created and the App ID Azure supplied to the `appsettings.json` file
6. Follow the remaining steps to deploy the bot
7. After the final step *wait* until the deployment endpoint returns JSON confirming the successful deployment
8. After a few minutes, go to Azure, click on your Azure Bot, then in the left menu, click on "Test in Web Chat" and try to communicate with the bot
9. Once you've run through the process, if you are not going to be working with this bot, delete the resource group to avoid charges

The deployment document has been recently updated, so if you carefully read and follow the outlined directions, you should have a working bot to build from. If you follow the steps exactly and then hit an issue while following them, it will be easier to determine what exactly is wrong.

Comment: The main problem is OP need to connect `app service URL` with the `Bot Messaging endpoint` that's it, bot cannot recognized the application.

Comment: I will try this again...i come back to you then :)

Comment: That is right, i think the bot it self is working fine but the connection is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean unable to set the messaging endpoint? It's simply `https://<app-service-url>/api/messages`